# How to dispose of unused GWT Widgets

Tags: gwt, gxt

A GWT+GXT UI module I'm working on uses switching between panels in order to achieve different kind of views. Very simplified example:

```
mainPanel.add(successPanel);
```

OR

```
mainPanel.add(errorPanel);
```

I've noticed that if errorPanel never gets used (attached) it never gets disposed.

I know that adding both UI elements to the DOM and toggling visibility should achieve the same result and provide proper GC, but, refactoring everything to do that might introduce a lot of other issues.

I've tried the following methods:

- attaching the unused elements to the RootPanel and then calling widget.removeFromParent().
- adding the unused elements to a live DOM element just before that live element gets disposed
- Calling DOM.setEventListener(widget.getElement(), null).
- making a helper class that provides a removeMethod regardless of attachment status:

```
  public static void removeWidget(Widget w) {
    if (w.getParent() == null) {
      RootPanel.get().add(w);
      if (RootPanel.isInDetachList(w)) {
        RootPanel.detachNow(w);
      } else {
        try {
          // onUnload() gets called *before* everything else (the opposite of
          // onLoad()).
          w.onUnload();
          AttachEvent.fire(w, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // ??? throws "Should only call onDetach when the widget is attached to the browser's document"
        } finally {
          // Put this in a finally, just in case onUnload throws an exception.
          try {
            w.doDetachChildren();
          } catch (Exception e) {
            // ???
          } finally {
            // Put this in a finally, in case doDetachChildren throws an exception.
            DOM.setEventListener(w.getElement(), null);
            //w.attached = false; // ??
          }
        }
      }
    } else if (w instanceof HasWidgets) {
      ((HasWidgets) w).remove(w);
    } else if (w != null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("This widget's parent does not implement HasWidgets");
    }

  }
```

None of these methods worked reliably. Is there any way to mark an unused widget as not needed and have GWT handle all the disposing, including its children?

Somehow related to my question, is there any way to figure out which widgets/classes are not being disposed of, short of a "roll-your-own" tracker?

Comment: First i would like to ask why not lazy initiating those widget only when needed and right before being attached to the dom? as long as those are not attached to the dom they are nothing but objects in memory once the all references to these widgets are removed they will be GCd, even when they are attached to the dom once they are detached they will also be GCd if they are not referenced.

Comment: Unfortunately the code base is already old and spread out, not so easy to refactor it. Looking to see if there's an easy solution before going extreme.

Comment: If the widgets is being referenced somewhere then i dont recall any other way to solve this other than cutting all references to the widget instance, and it has nothing to do with it being attached to the dom or not. should really look into the lazy creation and limiting those widgets scope.

Comment: That would be easier said than done, the views using them inherit from Widget so it requires complete refactoring in order to maintain functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "dispose" for GWT Widget - there is only attach/detach. If the widget is detached (or never attached), then normal garbage collection will work once you have no references to it.

If you leave it in "attached" mode, but actually remove all references to it (manually removing it from the DOM, or manually triggering attach without actually putting it in the DOM, etc), it will leak memory in *some* browsers (ancient firefox, IE6-9 or 10, etc).

Your steps of going through attach and detach have the same effect as never attaching it to begin with. Your leak is somewhere else, not in GWT Widget's lifecycle. There is no "dispose" in GWT - as long as it isn't actually attached, normal GC is enough.